# Ubuntu 13.10 Share non-OS drive with Windows

Tags: 13.10, windows-7, samba, shared-folders

I'm a total noob.

I've got a HP Microserver with Ubuntu 13.10 desktop installed. I've got a 250GB hard drive with the OS on there, and a 3TB drive I'd like to share with Windows.

I've managed to use Samba to share a folder in `Home` with no problems, but on the 3TB drive I'm having no joy at all, just an `unable to connect` message.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend formatting the 3TB drive in NTFS. This way you will be able to see it in Ubuntu and Windows without the need for any other steps. If you can not do this, then the next best thing would be to re-partition your 3TB drive to something smaller. Like 2TB. Then format the 2TB with NTFS (Using an app like gparted). Since NTFS is compatible with both OS, you won't have any problems sharing between both systems.

For sharing options with Samba I invite you to read: [Here's my smb.conf file. Whats wrong with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424722/heres-my-smb-conf-file-whats-wrong-with-it/424737#424737)

Comment: Adding the "force user xxx" to the smb.conf worked for me. Thanks (sorry I can't vote the answer due to bad reputation)