# Some Samba shares are not visible on network but still accessible by address

Tags: windows, samba, mate, shared-folders, caja

This has happened for as long as I can remember.  Nautilus/Caja shows a shared icon on the folders, and they are accessible from Windows by typing in their folder name, but they don't show up in the list of folders.

Other folders do show up in the list, even though there's nothing different about the Sharing Options in Nautilus.

If I change the shared name, they show up.  If I change it back, they disappear again.

Update:

I installed Ubuntu fresh on a new computer, shared two folders with `caja-share` with the same settings, and I can access one but not the other.  Both have the same owner, group, and permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 endolith endolith 4.0K Sep 28 19:35 notwork/
...
drwxrwxrwx 2 endolith endolith 4.0K Sep 28 19:35 works/
```

the one that works is in `/home`, the other is on `/mnt`, so that's probably the reason?

[image: caja-share settings]

[image]

It looks like the actual configuration for these are a bunch of text files under `/var/lib/samba/usershares`.  `/var/lib/samba/usershares/notwork` is:

```
#VERSION 2
path=/mnt/drivepool/notwork
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:F
guest_ok=y
sharename=notwork
```

`/var/lib/samba/usershares/works` is:

```
#VERSION 2
path=/home/endolith/works
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:F
guest_ok=y
sharename=works
```

So the only difference is the path, as alluded to but not really explained in [Here's my smb.conf file. Whats wrong with it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424722/heres-my-smb-conf-file-whats-wrong-with-it).

Mounting `drivepool` under my home folder doesn't fix it, either.  So it's not the path itself but something to do with being inside the mount, which is `mergerfs`.

I am sharing the files using `caja-share` ([`mate-file-manager-share`](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-file-manager-share)) under MATE desktop environment, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, but it also has the standard Ubuntu environment installed.

**Edit:**

A clue!  I found that Samba has log files for each machine that connects to it.

```
[2016/10/09 23:32:54.687515,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3259(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/win7backup failed. Permission denied
[2016/10/09 23:32:54.697705,  0] ../source3/smbd/service.c:199(set_current_service)
  chdir (/mnt/drivepool/Backups/win7backup) failed, reason: No such file or directory
```

There is such a directory, of course:

```
~> la /mnt/drivepool/Backups/
drwxrwxrwx 2 endolith endolith 4.0K Sep 26 22:42 win7backup/
```

Comment: Hi @endolith, can you mention what version of Ubuntu you are using and what Desktop environment you are using. I ask since (for me at least), only Ubuntu and not xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Mate or any other Ubuntu works perfectly when sharing. I would guess there is some sort of extra work done on Ubuntu to make it seem seamless and easy to use.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Ok I added it